# Run Java programs from PHP in a sandbox

Tags: java, php, exec, sandbox

I have a little question: we have to run Java programs and parts of the code will be uploaded by the users. 
So I want to know what's the best way to run them? I know 2 possible ways,

1. `exec("javac Usercode.class")` and then run the whole thing with `exec("java Main")`, but I tried it with `exec()` and it don't work. maybe because the http is not root? But I don't know exactly why.
2. http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/ ?

Any suggestions?

And another question is, how can I run these programs in a sandbox. we have a Debian server and so it's no problem to execute the command with a limited time, but is there a possible way to run the whole code in a sandbox?

Comment: What do you mean "it don't work"? Did you get any error messages? Was the output not what you expected? If you suspect it's a permissions issue, you can change to the user running your web server and try executing the program manually.

Comment: thanks, now it works..
how to sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideas for sandboxing:

- Run in a chroot using e.g. Debian's schroot command. Protects against them accessing files outside of the chroot but not against them doing things like opening sockets etc.
- Each user has their own Linux username against which they validate. Commands will then be run under the appropriate username (e.g. by using sudo or a set-uid executable).
- Maintain a pool of virtual servers - expensive and complicated but gives best isolation.